# bootstrap typeahead with dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I want typeahead suggestion menu to display different results according to the selected menu like the following structure:

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];
var numbers = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"];
var names = ["Ahmad", "Ali", "Hatem", "Wesam", "Nour", "Jeorge"];

$( "#search1" ).attr("autocomplete", "off");
$( "#search-fld" ).typeahead({source: colors});

$("#search-drop li a").click(function(){
    $("#search-btn").text($(this).text()); 
    if($(this).text() == 'People') {
        $( "#search-fld" ).typeahead({source: names});
    } else if($(this).text() == 'Salaries') { 
        $( "#search-fld" ).typeahead({source: numbers});
    } else if($(this).text() == 'Jobs') { 
        $( "#search-fld" ).typeahead({source: colors});
    }
});
```

Here is the example as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yabasha/mqqQZ/1/).
But the problem is that the same results keep appearing even if I choose different submenu.

I want to know how to load different typeahead results from different resources.

Please Advice,

===============================

[image: Dynamic typeahead error]

===============================

[image: New Error]

Comment: I see that your response is not properly formated, it should be as js array like `["a lite job 1", "accounting/banking/finance", "admin"]`.

Comment: could you please tell me how to format it, should I put the response in an array and get the data from the array? thanx for all your helps

Comment: You should return your data as json. I'm not sure what is your backend language but for example in PHP it looks like: `$data = array("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black");
$response = json_encode($data);`

Comment: I'm using tcl for the backend, do you know how to do it??

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with tcl. Search if there is any encoding function or format your data by your own in tcl. Althought it's just a string so add `[` and `]`, put values in apostrophe and separete values with comma in a loop.

Comment: After fixing the response from the server side and read them in the jquery side with the following code: $.get('/autocomp/keywords.adp', { type: 'key', format:'json' ,country:currentIso}, function (data) { $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = data; });

I still get repeated first character, as you can see in the new error screenshot

Comment: Try updateing your typeahead source like this `$( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Thank you very very very much :) :) :) for the great support

Comment: one more question please how can I add minLength = 2 to the code, I tried $.get('/autocomp/keywords.adp', { type: 'key', format:'json' ,country:currentIso}, function (data) { $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').minLength = 2, $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = JSON.parse(data); });

Comment: Set `minLength` attribute when you bind typeahead for the first time. Checkout the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mqqQZ/6/

Comment: Now when I set the typeahead for salaries to $.get('/autocomp/keywords.adp', { type: 'key', format:'json' ,country:currentIso}, function (data) { $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = data; }); and I set it to $.get('/autocomp/jobs-title.adp', { type: 'key', format:'json' ,country:currentIso}, function (data) { $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = data; }); for jobs, at first load the typeahead works fine for jobs and salaries but when I click on salaries and click again on jobs I get salaries typeahead, I've tried to unbind and bind the event again but the same result

Comment: Try with `$( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = JSON.parse(data);` instead of `$( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = data;`

Comment: I did {sorry I copied and past the old code} after doing that, the first time it displays the data correctly when first loading the page and by default the first option is jobs and the typeahead data displays correctly when changing to another option the typeahead data displays correctly for the second option, but when I return back to jobs typeahead data for salaries option appears, I thought that typeahead event for the second option stuck so I tried to unbind() and bind() again but no luck. Thanx a lot

Comment: This may be issue with the data you recieve. Check if your response doesn't have any signs like `'` or `"` that might break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#search-drop li a").click(function(){
        $("#search-btn").text($(this).text()); 
        if($(this).text() == 'People') {
            $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = names;
        } else if($(this).text() == 'Salaries') { 
            $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = numbers;
        } else if($(this).text() == 'Jobs') { 
            $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = colors;
        }
});
```

Comment: how can I add a remote data results for this example? Please advice.

Comment: If you want to load your data dynamically I sugest to use ajax calls to backend script where you make database query for examlpe. This is how it could look like:

`if($(this).text() == 'People') {
     $.post('/query', { type: 'People' }, function (data) {
            $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = data;
        });
}`

Comment: hi, I used $.get('/autocomp/keywords.adp', { type: 'key', country:usa}, function (data) { $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = data; }); I could see the request get successfully with 200 status and see the response words from developer tools but the problem when I want to try the auto complete it repeats the character I typed 8 times and when I type the second or third characters the auto complete list disappear

Comment: the response list I get from the request contains many words like: admin, list, state, ededes .....

Comment: if($(this).text() == 'People') { if($(this).text() == 'People') { $.post('/query', { type: 'People' }, function (data) { $( "#search-fld" ).data('typeahead').source = data; }); } and the response result I can see:

Comment: a lite job 1
accounting/banking/finance
achats
admin
administration
advertising

Comment: I added a screen shot above in the question